# C# save/retrieve an array of structures from settings file

Tags: c#, settings

I have a simple question (I think) that I'm not making much progress finding an answer to with Google.  I have a structure as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class to represent the sync settings for a single camera.
/// </summary>
public class CameraSyncSettings
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SyncPath { get; set; }
    public bool OverwriteExisting { get; set; }
};
```

And then an array of these in the program, one for each camera:

```
List<CameraSyncSettings> MyCameraSettings = new List<CameraSyncSettings>();
```

Now, what I want to do is have a property in my settings such that I can read/write this array into it to persist the information between sessions.

How can I do this and what is the best/most efficient way?

Comment: To clarify, what's the format of your "settings file"?  Is it XML?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Comment: It's the basic settings file you get with a C# project.  You know the one that integrates with VS.

Comment: I know it as Settings.settings in the UI.  Edit, which I guess becomes app.config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using Properties.Settings of type ListDictionary

```
    Example:
    Properties.Settings.Default.Example.Add("Setting1", new CameraSyncSettings());
    Properties.Settings.Default.Example.Add("Setting2", new CameraSyncSettings());
    Properties.Settings.Default.Example.Add("Setting3", new CameraSyncSettings());

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

see link for more information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

**NB: You can set the Scope of Properties.Settings.Default.Example to Application or User**

Answer (score 0):

As we've cleared in the comments you want to use app.config: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0) project should pretty much cover all your needs.